# Laravel double interpolation in blade file

Tags: php, html, laravel

Actually I've this :

```
<img src="/images/lang/{{Config::get('languages')[App::getLocale()]['flag-icon']}}_flag.jpg" class="lang-flag" alt="">
```

But I wan't to link this with the storage :
Example :

```
{{ Storage::url('images/user.svg') }}
```

I would have thought of doing this, but it obviously doesn't work, and I don't know how to do "double interpolation", there must be a simple way to do it but I'm stupidly stuck on it:

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url('images/lang/{{Config::get('languages')[App::getLocale()]['flag-icon']}}_flag.jpg') }}" class="lang-flag" alt="">
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything within `{{ }}` is PHP code so you can use simple string concatenation:

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url('images/lang/'.Config::get('languages')[App::getLocale()]['flag-icon'].'_flag.jpg') }}" class="lang-flag" alt="">
```

Comment: A break is necessary ! it was obvious, thank you very much for your help and sorry for this stupid question ;)